# Required fields within a p:tabView

Tags: validation, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, tabs

I have a jsf/primefaces page, with a tabView, that does not work as I would expect it to.

If I make a selection on tab 1, then move to tab 2 and save, it works fine. If I stay on tab 2 and save a second time, it displays the required message for the required field on the first tab.

If I return to the first tab, it is filled in, as it should be. If I press Save again now, on the first tab, it works again.

Why does jsf/primefaces think this field is not filled in?

Page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
  <h:head />
  <h:body>

    <div style="height: 50px;">
      <p:messages id="messages" autoUpdate="true" showDetail="true" closable="true" />
    </div>

    <h:form id="form">

      <p:tabView id="tabs" dynamic="true">

        <p:tab id="tab1" title="Tab 1">
          <h:outputLabel value="Field 1" />
          <h:selectOneMenu required="true" requiredMessage="Must fill in field 1 selection">
              <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select..." itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />
              <f:selectItem itemLabel="1" itemValue="1" />
          </h:selectOneMenu>
          <br/>
        </p:tab>

        <p:tab id="tab2" title="Tab 2">
          <h:outputLabel value="Field 2" />
          <p:inputText required="false" />
          <br/>
        </p:tab>

      </p:tabView>

      <p:commandButton value="Save" ajax="true" action="#{tabBean.action}" update="form"
          oncomplete="setTimeout(function(){$('[id$=messages]').fadeOut()},'500')" />

    </h:form>
  </h:body>
</html>
```

Bean:

```
@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean(name = "tabBean")
public class TabBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public TabBean() { }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){ }

    public void action() {
        // do the save, if validation doesn't fail first
        addJsfMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "OK", "no prob");
    }

    private void addJsfMessage(Severity severity, String summary, String detail) {
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(severity, summary, detail);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    }
}
```

While creating this sample, I found that either of the following changes got rid of the error, but neither is desirable:

- turning off dynamic loading (the primefaces documentation says `in dynamic mode, only the active tab contents
  are rendered and when an inactive tab header is selected, content is loaded with ajax`, which I assumed to mean *on the first load* but it seems to not just hide already-loaded tabs, but not render them at all)
- replacing the `<h:selectOneMenu ... />` with: `<h:inputText required="true" requiredMessage="Must fill in field 1 text" />`

Comment: That odd behaviour might not be understood unless explicitly stated by relevant [examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You're right. Added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's caused by the combination of `<p:tabView dynamic="true">` and `<p:commandButton update="form">`.

When (re)rendered, a dynamic tabview only contains the currently active tab, not others. Only when you change the tab, then it will be loaded into the HTML DOM tree asynchronously. Now, you're on submit updating the entire form, including the dynamic tabview, so it re-renders with only the currently active tab reloaded. In your particular case, the first tab doesn't exist in the HTML DOM tree at all and therefore nothing can be sent to the server side.

Try being more specific in `<p:commandButton update>`. Specify **only** the components which *really* need to be updated, not the entire form with the dynamic tabview.

Comment: That kind of makes sense, but if a tab isn't rendered, how does it know it isn't filled in? And why does swapping out the selectOneMenu for an inputText stop it from happening?